# Ambiguous column reference using a JSON operator on PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, function

I can't find a valid syntax to refer a JSON field on a PostgreSQL function.

I'm using a function to call some values from all my clients schemas, one of it is the rule_id, stored on a JSON type column. As show below:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT 
 r.id, r.created, r.type, r.asset_type, r.title, r.amount, r.earning_type, a.user_id, u.customer_id, 
 r.rule ->>' || 'id' || ' "rule_id"
 FROM ' || schemaName || '.reward AS r RIGHT JOIN ' || schemaName || '.avatar AS a ON r.avatar_id = a.id, 
_global.user AS u WHERE u.id = a.user_id
' 
;
```

The JSON field have this structure, and the id is on the main path (ex. Id:93):

```
object      {13}

updated :   null

    notificationRules       [0]

name    :   Level rule

script  :   null

levelStart  :   500

created :   2018-09-18T20:25:27.488+0000

    postRule        {12}

id  :   93

gamificationEventId :   platform.reward.XPChangedEvent

    gamification        {9}

levelIndex  :   2

levelEnd    :   1999
```

But it returns the following error:

> ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous
>   LINE 3:  r.rule ->>id "rule_id"

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Comment: If you were typing this query by hand, what would the `r.rule ->>id "rule_id"` part look like? Right now, `id` is an unquoted identifier so PostgreSQL is looking for an `id` column and finding several options, `"rule_id"` is a quoted identifier so once PostgreSQL can figure out what `id` means it will start looking for a `rule_id` column. Then it will get confused again because it won't know what two identifiers beside each other means.

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at the [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function; `format` is safer, cleaner, and much easier to read than string concatenation.

Comment: If `r.rule ->>' || 'id' || ' "rule_id"` is attempting to use the value of `r.id` as the field name or index to read, you should qualify it: `r.rule ->>' || 'r.id' || ' "rule_id"`. If not, and you're trying to access a json key called "id", then it needs to be in single quotes. And in either case there is no reason to use concatenation, it should be a string literal: `r.rule ->>''id'' "rule_id"`

Comment: thanks everybody. 

i've used: 

`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE E'SELECT 
 r.id, r.created, r.type, r.asset_type, r.title, r.amount, r.earning_type, a.user_id, u.customer_id,
 r.rule ->>\'id\' "rule_id"
 FROM ' || schemaName || '.reward AS r RIGHT JOIN ' || schemaName || '.avatar AS a ON r.avatar_id = a.id
 RIGHT JOIN _global.user AS u ON u.id = a.user_id
`